# For loop to add up areas of openings excluding certain rows keeps returning #VALUE! error?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

okay so i need to sum up the areas of all of the openings on a building excluding the ones on a wall, my Data looks like this and can have any number of rows:

[image]

The code looks like this and is a user defined function because I need to be able to re-arrange the Sheet without it breaking:

```
Public Function PermiabilityPercentage(CW, OW, Width, Height)
'This Function runs down a list of data that contains a notation for which wall an opening is on and the width and height of the door and using _
A cell with the comparative notation sums all of the area for openings where the notation matches and makes a percantage of total area with all of the openings.

'CW=Checking wall cell _
OW= Top cell of opening wall getting checked _
Width= top cell of the width of openings _
Height= top cell of the height of the openings

Dim DataRows As Integer
Dim TotalRows As Integer: TotalRows = OW.End(xlDown).Row
Dim Rowcnt As Integer

For Rowcnt = 0 To TotalRows Step 1
    If OW.Offset(Rowcnt) <> "" _
        Then
            DataRows = DataRows + 1
    ElseIf OW.Offset(Rowcnt) = "" _
        Then
            Exit For
    End If
Next Rowcnt

Dim Row As Integer
Dim TotalArea As Integer

Dim TotalAreaOther As Integer

For Row = 0 To DataRows Step 1
    If OW.Offset(Row) <> CW _
        Then
            TotalAreaOther = TotalAreaOther + (Width.Offset(Row) * Height.Offset(Row))
    End If
Next Row

PermiabilityPercentage = TotalAreaOther
Exit Function

'For Row = 0 To DataRows Step 1
'    If OW.Offset(Row) = CW _
'        Then
'            TotalArea = TotalArea + (Width.Offset(Row) * Height.Offset(Row))
'    End If
'Next Row

End Function
```

The commented-out part works perfectly and is extremely similar to the part that outputs TotalAreaOther that I was what I was checking.it always gave me the error. this isn't the final output of the code, but I do need these sums to finish.

currently

```
CW= A2
OW= A6
Width= D6
Height= E6
```

why does it keep giving me this error? all of the math should only be calculating numbers so I'm unsure why it is giving me a #VALUE! error.

Comment: If you call your function from a Sub you can debug it.

Comment: FYI you should use `Long` for whole numbers, so you can worry less about overflow.  There's no "saving" in using Integer over Long.

Comment: Is VBA a prerequisite? You know you can do it with a (not so) simple excel formula?

Comment: @TimWilliams i am very new to VBA as I only started teaching it to myself a couple of days ago, i will look up how to debug using sub thankyou for the advice, I will also make my variables long, I haven't memorised a lot of the types of variables yet but I will hopefully get better at choosing the right ones.

Comment: @VincentG Yes I could probably do what I want with excel formulas however this is just a small part of a much more complicated sheet that I am going to cut it back into once I have it working, and using a lot of excel formulas in cells is a lot harder to debug and would end up getting very messy and complicated, I am also currently teaching myself VBA, and while it isn't the best idea, I want to use it to solve as many things as possible to learn more about how to use it to it's fullest potential.

Comment: I have pieced it down to the line 

''
TotalArea = TotalArea + (Width.Offset(Row) * Height.Offset(Row))
''

However when the same bit of math runs in the other for loop it works fine? so im not sure why this one errors...

Comment: What's the actual error message you get on that line?

Comment: @TimWilliams I get the error "type mismatch", but not for the reason that RichardCook  has asked me to check, all of the data is just numbers. the reason I am getting this error is that when it runs through the FOR loop it seems to be skipping the first row of data when  row=0 and continuing one row past the end of the data. does .Offset(0) not just return the same cell? so it seems I get the error because it iterates past the end of the data as when i put numbers in the next row if completes. although I am not sure why

Comment: AH I have the solution, when I count my data in the first for loop to figure out how many rows there are I start at row 1 then count up, but as Offset() starts at 0 I need to start my counter at -1 so that it works correctly with the Offset() command, Thankyou everyone for your help especially @TimWilliams, I had no idea I could test my code this way and it should make debugging a lot easier in the future

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this might be a data problem rather than a code problem: an entry in either column D or column E is non-numeric in one of the rows with Wall position "A". The fact that it works correctly in rows that are not "A" tells us those rows all have numeric entries, and an "A" row must be the problem. Note that in some cases it might LOOK like a number to you, but Excel doesn't recognize it as a number. Verify the data in those columns.

To illustrate the issue, I set up an abbreviated version of your data. If all entries are numeric, the formula works:

[image: Working version]

But when I put an "x" in D6 it generates the #VALUE! error. Excel expects 2 numeric values for the statement `(Width.Offset(Row) * Height.Offset(Row))`. The #VALUE! error indicates that one of those entries is non-numeric (the wrong value type):

[image: Non-numeric entry]

Comment: you're right that it is because it isn't multiplying numbers but it seems to be because the code is skipping the first line of data and extending an extra line past it and therefore multiplying 2 blank cells, im not sure why I originally thought it was because then i outlined the "DataRows" variable it was starting at 1 and therefore equalling 13 at the end but that wasnt the case, now I think I may have used the .offset() command wrong?

Comment: Actually it does seem to do the first row my mistake, but it is still extending one row too far, if I figure out why I will update.